# Random Walk transition diagram on a lattice

Tags: diagrams, randomwalk

I want to draw a picture like this [image]

Which package should I use and how to write this code?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! You can use Ti*k*Z for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=0.7ex},x=2cm,auto,bend angle=40]
 \draw[->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0);
 \path (-1,0) node[bullet,draw=blue] (-a) {}
  (0,0) node[bullet,fill=red] (0) {}
  (1,0) node[bullet,draw=blue] (a) {};
 \foreach \Y [count=\X starting from -2] in {-2a,-a,0,a,2a} 
  {\draw (\X,0.05) -- (\X,-0.1) node[below]{$\Y$};}
 \draw[-{Stealth[bend]},thick] (0) to[bend left] node{$1/2$} (a);
 \draw[-{Stealth[bend]},thick] (0) to[bend left] node{$1/2$} (-a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `quotes` does not make the diagram better.